# Setting Access Form's Control value with VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to move my Access 2007 project to Access 2010.  Most of the coversion worked just fine, except for this bit of VBA code that I have.

This particular VBA code loads values from a PDF form, and then assigns those values to form controls.  This allows the user to enter their data manually, or to have someone else (who doesn't have access to the network where the Access DB is hosted) fill out the form and have someone import it for them.

When I run the code, it gets hung up in Access 2010 on the following code:

```
If Title <> "" Then
        Me!Title = Title 
End If
```

The error message I get is:

> Run-time error '2448':
>
> You can't assign a value to this object.

Here is some more background code, if that helps:

```
Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Dim theForm As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim jso As Object
    'Declare variables by Tab used in Form view
    'Tab 1
    Dim Title, First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Maiden_Name As String
```

...

```
'Form Load
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set theForm = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    theForm.Open (FileName.Value)
    Set jso = theForm.GetJSObject
```

...

```
'Tab 1 Data Load
    Title = jso.getField("Title").Value
```

...

```
'Data Display
    MsgBox "Values read from PDF:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Title:" & Title & vbCrLf & _
```

...

```
        'Tab 1 Data Populate
    If Title <> "" Then
        Me!Title = Title
    End If
```

In the code above, the value that I have in the form is correctly displayed in the Message box.  So I know that the variable is being filled with the correct value.  Also, I have the Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library referenced in the VBA Editor.  Again, this code worked just fine under Access 2007.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't assign anything to `Me!Title`.  In that context, `Me!Title` is read-only.

But what is `Me!Title`?  In debug mode, see what this says in the Immediate window:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(Me!Title)
```

Also while in debug mode, confirm you are not able to assign a string value to `Me!Title`:

```
Me!Title = "foo"
```

It seems you have more than one thing called "*Title*".  You `Dim` a variant Title.  And there is `Me!Title` ...  Maybe others?

It may help to avoid confusion to give them different names.  For example, 
if `Me!Title` is a text box, you could rename it to `txtTitle`.  And you could name the variant variable as `varTitle`.

I think you should also check the object browser and/or online help to see whether Access 2010 object model includes anything named `Title` which may be interfering here.